# rosdep update is requested repeatedly

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I followed the tutorial [Installing on Raspberry PI/Raspbian from source](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source) and have a problem at point 5.6. When I try the command "sudo rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy" I get the error "ERROR: your rosdep installation has not been initialized yet.  Please run: rosdep update". The command "rosdep update" has no effect and error message comes again. I run "sudo rosdep init" before.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE 1:**

**rosdep update**

```
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
Add distro "indigo"
updated cache in /root/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

With the sudo command (sudo rosdep update) it works and I could run after some fixes in the file "gbpdistro_support.py" the following command:

**sudo rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy --os=debian:wheezy**

but got another problem:

System dependencies have not been satisified:
apt     ros-groovy-urdf

**sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-urdf**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-urdf : Depends: ros-groovy-collada-parser but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-collada-parser**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-collada-parser : Depends: collada-dom2.4-dp-base (>= 2.4.0.16+rpi1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**I have built and installed the collada package  successfully how it was described in point 5.5.**

**UPDATE 2:**

The result is not much different.

**sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -yr --os=debian:wheezy**

```
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-groovy-urdf]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-urdf : Depends: ros-groovy-collada-parser but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-groovy-urdf] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-groovy-urdf]
```

**UPDATE 3:**

I need the package "collada-dom2.4-dp-base (>= 2.4.0.16+rpi1)" but there is no source or package via apt-get available.

**sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -yr --os=debian:wheezy --skip-keys=collada-dom**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-urdf : Depends: ros-groovy-collada-parser but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-groovy-urdf] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-groovy-urdf]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192156/rosdep-update-is-requested-repeatedly/) by [gus484](https://answers.ros.org/users/20145/gus484/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-08**:
Please show your commands and the console output from running them.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-09**:
To install system dependencies use rosdep install instead of check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WIth your manually installation of collada-dom you'll want to tell rosdep to skip that key as you've manually installed it.  Try using "--skip-keys=collada-dom" in your rosdep install invocation.

Edit re update 3:
Unless you're very lucky, you cannot install binaries on top of your custom compiled version of collada-dom. Any package which builds on top of that you'll want to build from source and not install the binary debian packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0